# issue with using wp_cache_get on server

Tags: wordpress

i am using below code that seems to work fine on my local server but when i use it live server , it just displays first page content on every page .

content does not changes on moving to next page while , pagination index show currnet page index though.

below is my code :

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: My News
 */
get_header();

// First, let's see if we have the data in the cache already
$the_query = wp_cache_get('m-in-news'); // the cache key is a unique identifier for this data

if ($the_query == false) {
    // Looks like the cache didn't have our data
    // Let's generate the query
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'pdf_cin_file',
                'compare' => '!=',
                'value' => '',
            ),
        ),
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'minnews',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'cache_results' => true
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    // Now, let's save the data to the cache
    // In this case, we're telling the cache to expire the data after 300 seconds
    wp_cache_set('m-in-news', $the_query, '', 300); // the third parameter is $group, which can be useful if you're looking to group related cached values together
}


$max_page = $the_query->max_num_pages;
$big = 999999999;
?>
<div class="master">
    <?php get_sidebar('presslistpages'); ?>
    <div class="rightSection">
        <h1><?php echo esc_html(get_the_title()); ?></h1>
        <div class="mNews">
            <div class="data_gird_content">
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    // Once we're here, the $query var will be set either from the cache or from manually generating the WP_Query object

                    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
                        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
                            $the_query->the_post();
                            $pdflink = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "pdf_cin_file");
                            $pdflink = isset($pdflink[0]) ? $pdflink[0] : '';
                            ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url($pdflink); ?>" target="_blank"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></div> <div class="details"><h2><?php echo esc_html(get_the_title()); ?></h2></div></a></li>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
            </div>
            <div class="paginationWrapper"><?php
                echo wp_kses(paginate_links(array(
                    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                    'total' => $max_page
                        )), array('a' => array_merge(cci_allowed_a_tag_attr(), array(
                        'href' => array()
                    )),));
                ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Would you please try In the _Settings → Permalinks_ panel, you can choose default permalink?

Comment: but seems is there some issue with  wp_cache_get('m-in-news'); as fine on my pc not on clients